# The content of some fields, though mandatory, are sometimes not being shown in my form responses

Tags: cognito-forms

I have created a form with several fields that must be filled before continuation is allowed. In configuration I chose that certain fields are always needed. It works well except that every now and then I receive a totally blank form where only the subject is filled in with an extra number (number of the subscription) but no email, no name, nothing else.

Why is required detail not being shown and how can I arrange that it is?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. Unfortunately, there is a problem with our form not displaying correctly in obsolete browsers. What is displayed is an empty form, no form fields, with a submission button.  As a result, when the form is submitted, our current validation logic does detect any fields to validate, thus allowing the form to be submitted. These are the blank form submissions you are receiving notifications on and the blank entries you see in entry management. We are currently working hard on a new payment forms release that will include a fix for this issue that will not allow the user to submit a form that is not displayed correctly for any reasons.